# what is best way to add data to elasticsearch in laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to elasticsearch and i want to add data to Mysql table and also elasticsearch in laravel.

I want to save in mysql with fewer fields and use relation with other tables  but i want to embed all related fields to one elasticsearch type.

I am using elasticsearch just for data mining.

What is best way to insert this data to elastis?

I should use logstash to insert data or insert directly??

Is it necessary to use beats in this situation?

Comment: If you found an answer helpful, could you mark it accepted as well? :)

Comment: thanks for your answers,I loged documents to a log file in laravel, and wrote a logstash config file as i want, and then used logstash to send them to elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the elasticsearch client for php like @margus suggests. For indexing the data into elastic, as far as i understand your problem, there are 2 ways to go about it.

1. If perhaps you are inserting data into mysql on a user request (like user registration etc.), you could consider firing an event on mysql-save which could later be processed off a Queue, and a script (or laravel command) can consume the event for indexing the data into elastic. The script would obviously have your application code for fetching the required data in the required format.
   If indexing isn't heavy or the application isn't meant to cater to many users, you could simply index the data into elastic after the mysql save and avoid deferring the task.
2. Or if it isn't important to update the elastic index on every mysql save, you could set up a cron task (anything that can be scheduled to run at regular intervals) and do the fetching and indexing there.

I haven't worked with logstash, but i think its main use case is reading off log files on servers that can be parsed in the logstash config file and synced with the ingesting server. I'm not sure but there could be plugins that allow reading from mysql, but then you'll not have the power to write complex application logic in your logstash config files. 
Even if you could, i'd prefer writing the application related code within the application (where other developers can read it, and change it easily since it is all in the same repository). So, if the data that you are indexing in elastic is of relevance to the application (unlike logs) and requires access to application logic, then you'd be better off writing the indexer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has Elasticsearch package https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch . It uses popular php elastic search library underneath https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

If you do not know much about elasticseach in general then there is more to learn that can be said here in a few sentences. I recomment starting to read from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_quickstart.html

Comment: so what is logstash for? i should add to elastic with these packages? or add to laravel log and then add those logs to logstash?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.

https://github.com/basemkhirat/elasticsearch/wiki/0.-Overview

It keeps you away from wasting your time by replacing array queries with a simple and elegant syntax you will love